# Change order creation after a successful payment in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Actually with WooCommerce, an order is create before the payement arrive (pending).

I need to remove this statut and create and order only when the payement is success for have something like this :

Customer order > Processing > Complete or Refund.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PSone **Wrong!** Order is created **before payment gateways process**, see that in `WC_Checkout` class for [`process_checkout()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#940-995) that is triggered once order is placed on checkout page…

Comment: That is simply not possible in Woocommerce… an order is always created before payment methods process.